# add word with each number in one line

Tags: python

i made var with input word , then the output of word is encode hex , but what i need is to made another var with number if the input are 10 , the output = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 , then i need to join the word with each number .. so the output would be , hexedWord1,hexedWord2,hexedWord3 ... etc .. here is my code

```
   num = raw_input("Inset the number of students. ")
   for num in range(1, num + 1)
        print num
        word = raw_input("Insert the name of student to encrypt it to hex. ")
        res = "0x" + word.encode('hex') + num

    print res
```

Comment: You need to add the following to your question: 1. Sample input 2. What you currently see with that sample input 3. What is wrong with that output 4. What you would like the output to look like

Comment: Your code reads `num+1` lines. Could you provide an example `num+1` lines, the corresponding output (literally) that you expect, and what your code produces instead?

Comment: there's a big problem in your explaining. either num = the input you ask from the runner of your script, or it is the iterator from range (1, num+1). you have to choose betweens what variables names mean.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
when you read input from user using raw_input the value is stored in "num" as string,
So range(1,num+1) throws an error.

So either use

```
num = input("Inset the number of students. ")
```

or

```
num = int(raw_input("Inset the number of students. "))
```

Secondly,
There is a missing colon(:) at the end of for

fix it like this:

```
for num in range(1, num + 1):
```

Thirdly, you are using the same variable "res" for storing the result of every stage, so it gets overwritten.
I prefer you use a list to store values

Declare a empty list before the for loop and append new result to it within the loop

Finally, this statement throws an error

```
res = "0x" + word.encode('hex') + num
```

Fix it by:

```
res = "0x" + word.encode('hex') + str(num)
```

What happened was that, you tried to concatenate 3 objects of different type using "+" which produces TypeError in Python

the Final code would be something like this:

```
num = input("Inset the number of students. ")
res = []
for num in range(1, num + 1):
    print num
    word = raw_input("Insert the name of student to encrypt it to hex. ")
    res.append("0x" + word.encode('hex') + str(num))

for r in res:
    print r
```

This should work (Assuming this is what you expect)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what you are asking, but from what I understand, you the encrypted student names separated by commas with their number following the name

There are a few errors with your code.  For one, `raw_input("Inset the number of students. ")` returns a string, but you use it like an integer.  To fix this, do `num = int(raw_input("Inset the number of students. "))`  There are further things you can do to keep the user from giving you something weird, but this will work.

Another problem is with `res`.  For each student, res is being reset.  You want the information to be added to it.  This could easily be done with a += operator, but if you want them separated by commas, the best thing I can think of is using an array that can be `join`ed together with commas later on.

All together, the code would look like this:

```
num = int(raw_input("Inset the number of students. "))
res = []
for num in range(1, num + 1):
    print num
    word = raw_input("Insert the name of student to encrypt it to hex. ")
    res.append("0x" + word.encode('hex') + str(num))

print ",".join(res)
```

Personally, using num as both the iterator of the for loop as well as num feels weird, but I'll let you keep that.